# Shell Scripts unable to Create New Files on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having a problem with a fresh Linux installation not allowing shell scripts that I execute to create folders and files. At first, I thought that this was an issue because I was not logged in with root access, so I tried again after signing in to root, but it was still happening.

The version of Linux that I am running is Red Star 3. For those who are not familiar with Red Star, it is North Korea's official Linux distribution based on Fedora. I was curious about it, so I decided to try it out in a virtual machine. I went through the installation process following the instructions from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svqU9DG1ZoE) to both complete the installation, and switch to the English language since I do not know Korean.

Why is this an issue and what can I do about it? The shell script that I am executing is only trying to place new files on the user's desktop, so there is really no reason that it should not be possible. I have researched changing folder permissions using `chmod`, but I have never used `chmod` before, so I do not really understand how it works, and all of the different commands that use it that I have found online have not fixed the problem.

**Image is part of a response to [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1132194/shell-scripts-unable-to-create-new-files-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment1623751_1132194):**

[image: Red Star 3 Terminal Output]

**Image is part of a response to [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1132194/shell-scripts-unable-to-create-new-files-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment1624530_1132194):**

[image: Red Star 3 Terminal Output]

**Image is part of a response to [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1132194/shell-scripts-unable-to-create-new-files-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment1633954_1132194):**

[image: Red Star 3 Terminal Output]

Comment: This may be a virtual machine issue.  Which are you using? Did you create enough disk space? Is the disk space you created writeable? If you "df -h" in that linux box is there space?

Comment: @strobelight The virtual hard drive is 100GB, and the physical hard drive that it is stored on is 1TB, and there is nothing on it right now except for the virtual hard drive, so there's definitely enough space. I am using VirtualBox for virtualization.

Comment: OK, `cd $HOME`, `id`, `ls -ld *`, there should be Desktop or desktop directory. What does the line containing the desktop directory show? The 3rd field is the owner, and that should match the result of the id command, ensuring you have ownership.

Comment: @strobelight I've added a screenshot of the resulting output to the original question. I posted it yesterday, but forgot to write a comment stating such and hadn't noticed until now.

Comment: Hmm, `cd -P Desktop`, `df -h .`  (that -P may be lower case, not at my computer, commenting via the Stack Exchange app)

Comment: @strobelight I have added another screenshot of the resulting output. I have no idea what the significance of the command is, but it looks to me like you were trying to verify the accuracy of what I said about the virtual machine's hard drive space. By the way, it looks like `-P` is correct.

Comment: the -P takes you to the location as physically known by the system, then the df shows how much space is left.  How 'bout a zero-length file in the Desktop directory: `touch zero_length_file` does that give you permission denied too?

Comment: @strobelight I do not get a permission denied error from executing `touch zero_length_file`, but nothing displays in the console either.

Comment: If no errors I wouldn't expect an output, just the file presence, so you should now see that file on the Desktop.

Comment: With the VM powered off, select the VM, click Settings (or right click the VM and choose settings), click Storage, and confirm any icons which look like CD/DVD are Empty (i.e., not pointing to isos on your own disk)?

Comment: @strobelight The file is present in my user home directory, but not on the desktop even though I `cd`'d to my desktop. I have also checked the VM settings. Nothing is mounted in the disk drive.

Comment: @strobelight Never mind. The file is in the correct location. I saved the command that I entered in a text file and I did not `cd` in to my Desktop.

Comment: @strobelight Any advice on what to do? I still have not solved this problem.

Comment: what does the output of `mount` show?

Comment: @strobelight I have added yet another screenshot to the original post showing the resulting output.

Comment: @strobelight I tried disabling selinux as melds suggested but that has not solved the problem.

Comment: @strobelight Any further ideas about this? I still have not figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read that distribution has selinux enabled. You may want to try to check that (`sestatus`) to see if it's running. If it is you may need to make an exception for your script (see `chcat` and `chcon`) or disable selinux (`echo 0 > /selinux/enforce` should disable it temporarily or you can modify /etc/selinux/config).

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I tried it but it has not solved the problem.